# PWA Start forces internet connection

Tags: vaadin, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to run my app on my laptop that has wildfly installed but with no internet connection (internet connection should not be required since wildfly is my server). When my Vaadin PWA starts up, it says an internet connection is required. Is there a simple way to not require the internet?

No real good solutions I could find to try. Tried setting worker service in Chrome to offline.

Comment: Please take a look at this issue and the mentioned workarounds. https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13616

Comment: I turned on my mobile hotspot on my phone and had my laptop connect to it (even though my phone did not have internet connection) and it worked enough to have Vaadin think there was an internet connection available.